# Declare constant in C language

Tags: c

I am learning C language. I was reading to declare constants. What is the difference between

```
#define PI 3.1415927
```

and

```
float const PI = 3.1415927;
```

Thanks.

Comment: One is a preprocessor definition, the other is an actual constant.

Answer (score 2):

1. `#define` is text replacement. All occurrences of `PI` in your code will be replaced by `3.1415927` before compilation.
2. `const` creates read-only variables. That means you can't assign to them, but you still can't use them as e.g. `case` labels, because they're not true constants.

Comment: Note: This is rather an incomplete list of differences, a more complete list can be found in the duplicate questions answers.

Comment: What's missing (apart from the `#ifdef` stuff)?

Comment: Well, taking address (possible with const variable), converting to string (possible with preprosessor), differences in using as array size (variable creates a VLA, technically), from the top my head.

Comment: @hyde Taking address is possible with variables in general (covered by #2) and not possible with literals (covered by #1). String conversion is possible with all macro arguments; I don't see how that applies. Why would you use `float PI` as the size of an array?